# angularjs : dynamic key in repeat var

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to access to the value of the key id of the object `{{categorie.categories.id}}` but id is a var from `ng-repeat="c in cats"`. 
It is possible to do a think like this:  `{{categorie.categories.(c.id)}}`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/BdWJOGsL5JAZk4zdpV61 ? If this is what you are after, you need to use $index. See documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, it should be:

```
{{categorie.categories[c.id]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the key use the following.

```
<a ng-repeat="(key,val) in cats">{{key}}, {{val}}</a>
```